# Solution existence of quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be real parameters. Prove that 
$$
ab(x-a)(x-b)+bc(x-b)(x-c)+ca(x-c)(x-a)=0
$$
has a solution **without using intermediate value theorem**.

**My attempt.** The above equation is equivalent to
$$
(ab+bc+ca)x^2-[ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)]x+(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)=0.
$$
We consider two cases:

**Case 1.**  $ab+bc+ca=0$

The above equation is equivalent to
$$
(3abc)x-2abc(a+b+c)=0.
$$
This equation always has a solution.

**Case 2.** $ab+bc+ca\ne 0$
$$
\Delta=[ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)]^2-4(ab+bc+ca)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)
$$
Let $u=a+b+c, v=ab+bc+ca, w=abc$. We have
$$
\Delta=(uv-3w)^2-4v(v^2-2uw)=u^2v^2+2uvw+9w^2-4v^3.
$$
We try to prove that $\Delta\geq 0$ but we cannot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$p(a)p(b)p(c)=bc(a-b)(a-c)ca(b-c)(b-a)ab(c-a)(c-b)\le0.$$

Then there is at least one change of sign.

Comment: Please explain clearly your answer....

Comment: I habe found an even simpler approach.

Comment: Without using intermediate value theorem????

Comment: @Blind: mh, you need a lemma saying that if a quadratic function takes the two signs, it has a real root.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't so far from a solution.

You want to prove that

$$\Delta:=9w^2+(2uv)w+(u^2v^2-4v^3) \ \ \text{is always positive}$$

You have noticed that $\Delta$ has been "organized" as a quadratic in variable $w$ with positive dominant coefficient $9$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for a quadratic with positive dominant coefficient to be always positive is that it has no (real) roots, i.e., that its discriminant $\delta$ is always negative.

This means :

$$\delta:=16v^2(9v-8u^2) \ \ \text{has to be proven always} \ \leq \ 0$$

$$\iff \dfrac{v}{u^2} \leq \dfrac{8}{9} \tag{1}$$

(1) is a consequence of the fact that :

$$\dfrac{v}{u^2}=\dfrac12\left(\tfrac{(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2}\right)=\frac12-\underbrace{\dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2(a+b+c)^2}}_{\ge 0} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$

Remarks :

1) It remains to treat apart the case where $a+b+c=0$ (for which (1) and (2) would have a zero denominator).

2) Take a look at the following picture displaying two curves :

$$f(x):=ab(x-a)+bc(x-b)(x-c)+ca(x-c)(x-a)$$

(red parabola) and :

$$g(x):=\dfrac{f(x)}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}=\dfrac{ab}{x-c}+\dfrac{bc}{x-a}+\dfrac{ca}{x-b}$$

(curve in blue with three asymptotes) for the following values : $a=-0.5, \ b=-1.5, \ c=1.$

with common roots (of course).
[image]